# Super capacitor discharge protection

Tags: capacitor, protection, short-circuit, discharge, supercapacitor

We are developing an active RF timing tag which uses a 3 V 20 F super capacitor as a power source. We will charge the tag at the time of registering a participant. The charge time should be as short as possible (around 5 s) this entails a high current charger (around 10 A). The charger (BQ24640 or MAX17701) is separate from the tag and is powered from a battery bank.

The problem I am trying to solve is how to protect the tag from accidental or malicious discharge during the event as the tag charging pads are exposed.

I initially thought that a diode would do the job but due to the high currents involved there will be substantial forward voltage losses during charging. This is a concern as our events are mostly in remote locations and as mentioned we will be charging the tags using a battery bank.

I am not an electronics engineer so any suggestions as to how to protect our tag from reverse current discharge would be most appreciated! The simpler the better and component cost is important factor.

Thanks in advance.

Peter

Comment: Welcome! Ideal charging would be CC-CV, set for 3 V and as high current as your supercap can tolerate.

Comment: Hi Winny, thanks for your welcome message. I agree with CC-CV but current capability of the PCB contacts and tracks is a current limiting factor. Anyway, I think we have the charging covered - the main issue now is to how to protect the capacitor from discharging via accidental or malicious short circuiting of the exposed charging contacts...

Comment: Alright, then limit it to whatever sets the limit for you. A Schottky diode would solve your accidental discharge problem.

Comment: A 12 A 20 V Schottky diode can be found for ~US$1 or less at https://www.mouser.com/c/semiconductors/discrete-semiconductors/diodes-rectifiers/schottky-diodes-rectifiers/?if%20-%20forward%20current=12%20A&vrrm%20-%20repetitive%20reverse%20voltage=20%20V, for example. How sensitive it would be to ESD, e.g., from walking across a carpeted floor, is another question. BTW, any entrant "in the know" could extend time with a Li cell and two pins.

Comment: Hi Winny, I had thought of using a Schottky diode but the losses are still significant at the currents we are using. I am also considering an ideal diode.  Maybe there is another way. I am thinking of a normally open FET switch that would be activated/powered only when charging. When the charger is removed the FET switch would open. I'm not sure how to implement such a circuit. Any thoughts?